# MLS / IDX Data in the form of XML

Tags: wordpress, rets, mls, idx

I have an issue and I have been struggling with for weeks, almost a month, I am working on this website for a real estate agent in Toronto, Ontario and the last thing I have to do is get the listing on her website. We are using Wordpress wp-residence theme, this theme is compatible with iHomefinder, however the data I get from iHomefinder does not work with the themes features (maps, searches and even styles) I read somewhere that the only way to use these theme features is to add the listing manually. I found this plugin that will import all the listings

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-residence-add-on-for-wp-all-import/

But now I need to get my listings in the form of XML, CSV or XLS. I have all my login info and url to get my listing, however in the instructions it says I need to connect via RETS Client, which I do not have...is there anyone out there who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use an [IDX plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/rets/).

Comment: Do any of these do an export of the listings?

Comment: I'm not sure. PHP has a library for RETS if you want to write the code yourself: https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki. RETS is done with basic HTTP. You can even do it in your browser: https://www.flexmls.com/developers/rets/tutorials/example-rets-session/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also look over https://mlsimport.com .This plugin should help you import data from MLS. But is a paid version.